# XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] In Prism modules where

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I seem to understand that to optimize an app you need to add the following
to your app class

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
 namespace MyAppNamespace
 {
     public partial class App 
     {
     }
 }
```

Now if you have many Prism modules where do you add this line of code

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place it anywhere, but typically you would include it in the `App.xaml.cs`.  The "assembly" attribute will apply it to all pages in the project.

Comment: I m using Prism and I have placed above the namespace in app.xaml.cs however I seem to have read that you have many projects like I do  that each project should be having it.I am using .net standard for prism module without assemblyinfo file and I would like to avoid to go to each view and add it .Wondering if there was a general place I could put it. Hope it's clear what I am asking

Comment: AFAIK you can place it anywhere in a project and it will apply to all XAML pages in the project

Answer (score 0):

You would need the attribute in each project where you have XAML files. Some general rules:

- You can place this on individual XAML based Views/Pages to Opt-In or Opt-Out of Xaml Compilation:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public class ViewA : ContentPage
{
}

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
public class ViewB : ContentPage
{
}
```

- You can use it instead as an Assembly Attribute like you have shown which is what most people choose to do.

The important thing here is that you can only place this ONCE per project, and it is on a Project by Project basis. You can put it in any file you choose as that comes down to preference. Typically you see this in one of the following locations:

- In `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs`. Though most templates no longer include this file by default for SDK Style projects, many people (myself included) still prefer a central location to look for and add assembly level attributes
- In `App.xaml.cs` like:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace AwesomeApp
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
    }
}
```

- In an implementation of `IModule` which resides in a separate project

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace AwesomeApp.Auth
{
    public class AuthModule : IModule
    {
    }
}
```